# How to run debug and test modes simultaneously in Meteor

Tags: javascript, debugging, testing, meteor, mocha.js

I'm new to meteor. My use-case is I need to basically achieve same thing as running both

```
meteor run
```

and

```
TEST_WATCH=1 meteor test --driver-package meteortesting:mocha
```

simultaneously.

I need both to watch my tests results in my terminal console and run meteor with **--inspect** argument so I can track node script console.logs and other debugging information in Chrome remote debug session.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I think you may rather go using chimp, which uses webdriver and allows to remotely "manipulate" your application while the app is running in normal mode. Check https://guide.meteor.com/testing.html#acceptance-testing

Comment: Actually running the second command on separate port did the trick for me. Thanks anyway.